# Uncaught DOMException: This track is already set on a sender. connectycube.min.js:1

Tags: connectycube

I am using ConnectyCube to implent videocalling, but it sometimes works, sometimes not, I don 't know what is the meaning of "Uncaught DOMException: This track is already set on a sender. connectycube.min.js:1", so that I can not solve it and in the web I don't find any solution. This happended after I closed the browser, after this the videocalling stopped of working.

Thanks for any help.

**Mozilla**
[image]

**Chrome**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I already found the problem, it was this line:

```
const calleesIds = [$('#hd_idprofesional').val(), id_paciente]; /User's ids/
```

to

```
const calleesIds = [id_paciente]; /User's ids/
```

Docs say this:
Important note: The calleesIds array must contain the opponents ids only and exclude current user id.